# Is the connection by google-api-php-client SSL?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am accessing Google Cloud API (Calendar, Sheets) resources from my php app by authenticating as a service account.
Is the communication made by google-api-php-client encrypted?
I want to know if my service account credentials are being transferred securely over https.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if my service account credentials are being transferred securely over https.

`https` stands for `Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure`. So yes, it is secure. `https` always involves SSL. As long as the SSL-Certificates are valid, (which they propably are), everythig is fine.

Comment: Thank you wuerfelfreak!
My server has a valid SSL certificate, so I assume that the connection between the server and the user is secure.
Do you know how I can verify that the communication between google-api-php-client and the Google Cloudl API is SSL?